# Outlook code is working when manually called but giving trouble from Application_ItemSend

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a code that checks the recipient of the mail, looks what organization is set in the address book for the recipient and dependent on that sets the "SentOnBehalfOfName"-property of the item. If the recipient is working for client2, he will get the mail from "we_love_to_serve_client2@domain.com".

I call the code either before sending the mail via a button in my ribbon, that calls this Sub:

```
Sub Signatur()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
 Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
 Set olApp = Outlook.Application
 Set objMail = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
Call Signatur_auto(objMail)
End Sub
```

I do this if I want to know which mail-adress is going to be chosen.

In the itemSend-section of thisOutlookSession I also call the same sub

```
Call Signatur_auto(Item)
```

Part of the Signatur_auto (i do not copy that in, the question is too long already...) is dealing with the SentOnBehalfOfName-property, the other part is putting the item into the right folder. The Folder is chosen depending on the SentOnBehalfOfName-property.

Now comes the interesting part: Although the folder-part is always working (which can only be when the SentOnBehalfOfName has worked before), the SentOnBehalfOfName only works "half". In the preview-line the mail sent is shown as from "we_serve_client2@domain.com", but when I open the mail it says it was sent by me. The Client always only sees my address, and also answers to my address - which I do not want....

How cant be, that the same code is having different results dependent on where it is called? Is it a Problem to change the sendonbehalf-field in the item send-section?

Thanks for any Inputs!
Max

Answer (score 2):

Why it does not work?

Try this in ItemSend.

```
Dim copiedItem As mailItem

Set copiedItem = Item.Copy
copiedItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "we_love_to_serve_client2@domain.com"
copiedItem.Send    
Item.delete
Cancel = True ' In case your setup generates an error message as described in the comments
```

Why it works? Appears "copiedItem.Send" bypasses ItemSend.

Comment: i am not sure if this is funny or if I should give way to despair... the code does change the behaviour in two ways:
1. the Sender is now ok
2. the "SaveSentMessageFolder" does not work anymore...

bythe way two changes to your code:
- there is no Need to set the sentonbehalfname there, this is already done before.
- added     Cancel = True so there Comes no error about sending a deleted item

Thanks Max

Comment: @Max I am the owner of a shared mailbox. Sent mail is in the shared mailbox Sent Items.

Comment: my code is always saving the sent mails into the inbox of the relevant shared Mailbox; with your code this function is not working anymore - this is really a strange thing!
Thanks Max

Comment: This in fact solves my issue where setting `SendUsingAccount` in `ItemSend` recently stopped working. Oh but it is so damn ugly I'm not sure I can live knowing that this is happening every time I send an email.